# Help with finding a set that meets certain criteria

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ 
That for a given $k\epsilon \mathbb{N}^{+}$ 
The following is an equivalence relation: 
$R_{A}=\left \{ <x,y> | y-x \epsilon A  \right \}$ 
And: $ \left | \mathbb{Z}/R_{A} \right |=k $

Any direction on how should I start to think to construct the set A?

Thank you

Comment: By "an equivalence class" did you mean "an equivalence relation"?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've corrected this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about $A = k \cdot \mathbb Z$?

Comment: If you are not familiar with the notation: $k \cdot \mathbb Z := \{ k \cdot z \mid z \in \mathbb Z \}$.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason when I've been checking this option I thought that the size if the quotient set wasnt k, but it is :)

Comment: @Jonathan You're welcome (: